# No me tira el resultado esperado cuando uso el inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, .net

el primer codigo me trae el resultado bien

```
select  t.TransaccionId, t.NetAmount, t.UserId, t.Id_movimiento, t.CreatedDate
from TablaPrincipal t where id_movimiento is null
```

el segundo codigo

```
select  t.TransaccionId, t.NetAmount, t.UserId, t.Id_movimiento, t.CreatedDate, u.nombreApellido_usuario
from TablaPrincipal t
inner join Usuarios u on t.UserId = u.Id_usuario
where id_movimiento is null
```

pero cuando meto el inner join no me trae nada! alguna idea?

Comment: Sí, no hay usuarios en la tabla `Usuarios` que tengan `id_movimiento` NULL en la tabla `TablaPrincipal`

Comment: usa `LEFT JOIN` este te muestra los datos aunque tenga NULL en la tabla relacionada

Comment: En SQL, no hay forma de saber si la consulta está bien on mal, sin ver un conjunto de los datos que hay en cada tabla y la salida que esperas obtener de cada una. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba utilizando un `Left Join`.

*Ejemplo:*

```
select  t.TransaccionId, t.NetAmount, t.UserId, t.Id_movimiento, t.CreatedDate, u.nombreApellido_usuario
from TablaPrincipal t
Left join Usuarios u on t.UserId = u.Id_usuario
where id_movimiento is null
```

Verifica que la relación que estás haciendo en las tablas está bien hecha y son basadas en sus llaves.